# Adobe Illustrator CS6 Missing SVG Save Option

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, cs6, data-merge

According to the following documentation, page 472 :

> https://help.adobe.com/archive/en/illustrator/cs6/illustrator_reference.pdf

... I should be able to :

1. Choose File > Save As, enter a filename, select SVG as the file format, and click Save.
2. Click More Options, and select Include Adobe Graphics Server Data. This option includes all information needed for variable
   substitution in the SVG file.

... but the problem is that there is no option for, "Include Adobe Graphics Server Data" :

> [image: Adobe Illustrator CS6 SVG 'More Options' Save Dialog Box]

... any ideas?¿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the CS6 Guide but probably working in CC...

*"The graphics server has been discontinued, and the same goes for that option."*
https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/illustrator-cc-removed-option-for-svg-include-adobe-graphics-server-data/m-p/9255708